# How to format a disk in VMware, using Python from a remote system?

Tags: python, vmware

I have a VMWare system and a Windows system. I want to run a python script which shall access the VMWare system via IP and then query for the Virtual Disks, format it, without user intervention and create a Datastore on it?

While much of the code is ready, i am unable to keep the "fdisk" process open and enter the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet is like :

```
$host1 = "<HostIP>"
Connect-VIServer -Server $host1 -User user -Password pass
$vmname = Get-VM
$n = $vm = 0
$datastore = Get-Datastore DS*     
for($i = 0; $i -le $num_disks; $i++) {
        $size = $datastore[$i].CapacityGB - 1     #Deducting 1GB from each Datastore. Full sized DS as a VM fails as it need some space to write VM data
        $vmnamenew = $vmname[$i]
        write-host "Size of VMDK to be added : ", $size
        write-host "VMname will be           : ", $vmnamenew
        write-host "Datastore used is        : ", $datastore[$n]
        New-HardDisk -vm $vmnamenew -CapacityGB ($size) -Datastore $datastore[$n] -StorageFormat $format    #Mounting the Datastore to VMs.
        Start-Sleep -s 20
```

> Blockquote